# How do I import a jQuery plugin via webpack and put it under $/jQuery? (ES6 + TypeScript)

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, jquery-plugins, ecmascript-6

I have these lines of code:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import * as jQuery from "jquery";
import "exports?Arrive!arrive";
```

The [arrivejs](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive) npm package is a jquery plugin. It lacked module.exports and basically just had "var Arrive" in it. Thanks to WebPack I managed to get it into my app, but now I want to put its methods underneath jQuery and $. Like following

```
$.arrive(".coolclass", function() { // do something });
jQuery.arrive(".coolclass", function() { // do something });
```

I have made by own interface for arrivejs. I recently added JQueryStatic because it didn't seem to work otherwise (I just started following ES6 compliancy)

```
interface JQuery {
    arrive(selector: string, options: ArriveOptions, callback: Function): JQuery;
    arrive(selector: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindArrive(): JQuery;
    unbindArrive(selector: string): JQuery;
    unbindArrive(callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindArrive(selector: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindAllArrive(): JQuery;
    leave(selector: string, options: LeaveOptions, callback: Function): JQuery;
    leave(selector: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindLeave(): JQuery;
    unbindLeave(selector: string): JQuery;
    unbindLeave(callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindLeave(selector: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindAllLeave(): JQuery;
}

interface JQueryStatic {
    arrive(selector: string, options: ArriveOptions, callback: Function): JQuery;
    arrive(selector: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindArrive(): JQuery;
    unbindArrive(selector: string): JQuery;
    unbindArrive(callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindArrive(selector: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindAllArrive(): JQuery;
    leave(selector: string, options: LeaveOptions, callback: Function): JQuery;
    leave(selector: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindLeave(): JQuery;
    unbindLeave(selector: string): JQuery;
    unbindLeave(callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindLeave(selector: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindAllLeave(): JQuery;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this? I've been at it for hours now..

Update: I want to put arrive and the rest under window/jquery elements.

Currently, this is working properly:

```
document.arrive("div", function () { console.log("works!");});
```

But I want to change that to

```
$(document).arrive("div", function () { console.log("works!");});
```

Comment: The link to the library is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who was struggling with this for my particular situation (ES6, Typescript, webpack), I had to add this to the top of the arrive.js file.

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
```

Then when I imported arrive to global scope, I had to do it like this:

```
import * as $ from "jquery"; //Present since before, likely relevant
import * as jQuery from "jquery"; //Present since before, likely relevant

import "exports?Arrive!arrive"; // <-
```

Thanks to Uzair for supporting me on Skype. His answer makes perfect sense too, just wasn't directly relevant to my issue.

As a bonus, this is what my typescript definition looks like for arrive. I haven't made a PR with it because I haven't written tests for it (required to submit) but someone is free to do it for me, or just create your own file straight off.

```
// Type definitions for Arrive 2.3.1
// Project: https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive
// Definitions by: William Bernting <https://github.com/qvazzler>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

interface ArriveOptions {
    fireOnAttributesModification?: boolean;
    onceOnly?: boolean;
    existing?: boolean;
}

interface LeaveOptions {
    fireOnAttributesModification?: boolean;
    onceOnly?: boolean;
    existing?: boolean;
}

interface Document {
    arrive(selector: string, options: ArriveOptions, callback: Function): JQuery;
    arrive(selector: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindArrive(): JQuery;
    unbindArrive(selector: string): JQuery;
    unbindArrive(callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindArrive(selector: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindAllArrive(): JQuery;
    leave(selector: string, options: LeaveOptions, callback: Function): JQuery;
    leave(selector: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindLeave(): JQuery;
    unbindLeave(selector: string): JQuery;
    unbindLeave(callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindLeave(selector: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindAllLeave(): JQuery;
}

interface JQuery {
    arrive(selector: string, options: ArriveOptions, callback: Function): JQuery;
    arrive(selector: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindArrive(): JQuery;
    unbindArrive(selector: string): JQuery;
    unbindArrive(callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindArrive(selector: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindAllArrive(): JQuery;
    leave(selector: string, options: LeaveOptions, callback: Function): JQuery;
    leave(selector: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindLeave(): JQuery;
    unbindLeave(selector: string): JQuery;
    unbindLeave(callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindLeave(selector: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    unbindAllLeave(): JQuery;
}
```

Comment: I had a similar experience with webpack, TS, es6, and jquery-textcomplete. The two keys in this answer that helped me were 1) Change the import jquery to include the `* as`, and 2) Change the jquery-textcomplete from `import textcomplete from 'jquery-textcomplete'` to the bare `import 'jquery-textcomplete'`. Thanks for providing the help.

Answer (score 2):

Arrive.js binds its methods to jQuery elements, not with the `jQuery` or `$` object itself. Try this:

```js
$(document).arrive(".coolclass", function() { // do something });
```

The `Arrive` object exposes only two methods `Arrive.unbindAllArrive()` and `Arrive.unbindAllLeave()` all other arrive methods are bound to javascirpt and jQuery elements.

Secondly, arrive.js does not depend on jQuery. From the docs:

> The library does not depend on jQuery, you can replace jQuery elements in the examples below with pure javascript elements and it would work fine.

Comment: Ok, I did not know that. I'm still not sure how to put it under jQuery elements though? I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).arrive is not a function` if I try to do $(document).arrive

Comment: It's a chrome extension. I use npm but it's all client-side from there.

Comment: After doing more checking, it appears that $ is not accessibly inside Arrive. I forced it in there by using `import "exports?Arrive!imports?$=jquery!./arrive.js";`, but it still does not seem to work.. That may be a webpack issue but I think the original issue might be about es6 compliancy?

Comment: `document.arrive("div", function () { console.log("works!");});` this is working. Now how do I move that to be under a JQuery element? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The solutions already posted seem outdated as `import "exports...` just does not work anymore or some info is missing.

Anyway, my solution is to first add the type definitions via

[`npm install --save @types/arrive`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/arrive)

then import the types in the concerning `ts` file by using the [ES6 import style](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/596#issuecomment-76014256)

`import 'arrive';`

and finally use Arrive.js like

`document.getElementsByClassName(".my-element")[0].arrive(...)`

Comment: The accepted answer was for Arrive 2.3.1, but back then, Arrive was exposed as a window variable. That's why exports was used (a webpack loader), to shim it into an export.